# Should I use JWT or Sessions for my eCommerce website?

Tags: django, rest, api, session, jwt

I'm building an eCommerce website for a personal project. It uses React for the front-end and a REST API running on django for the back-end. I want the user to be able to add items to a shopping cart and place an order without the need for an account.

For guest users, using a session/cookie to store info is great, but when it comes to logged in users, I would want to use the database to store items in a cart. That would require creating a user and giving them an auth token so they can perform necessary actions.

So should I use session/cookie authentication or is there a better way to achieve what I want using JWT?

Answer (score 1):

Both approach can work very well. However, I am currently working on something similar and I would personally recommend the simpler option which is the classic session approach. JWT tokens can be harder to maintain and sometimes insecure if not done correctly. Also, JWT tokens will not persists between logins.

In both ways, I don't see why one would be better to create and maintain a cart except maybe that a session system can actually store the complete cart in the session itself. You can then implement sessions controllers at the API level. 
ex: GET `"https://{host}/api/cart"` returns the items in the session's cart.

```py
# Django session
request.session['cart_id'] = cartId

# JWT Tokens
jwt.encode({‘cart_id’: cartId} ...
```

little note.. It can be harder to setup the sessions if you are working on localhost for react and a remote server for your API. (The cookies are generally set per domain).

Answer (score 0):

I am using JWT, and I think if you are using a database, you can create a generated JWTby user then store it in the database, you can control the availability of your jwt, in parameters, and I find the best way to secure your APIs, is to add the JWT token to the headers.

Comment: i would just store a session at that point. the whole point of jwt is not needing to query a db no?

Answer (score 0):

I would use Cognito authentication and integrate it with react and the backend api. It will help to manage the users outside the application.

Answer (score -1):

If you’ll be hosting your application in AWS, Check out AWS Cognito, it’s an identity and a user pool service. Their free tier is quiet generous. That, together with AWS Amplify which is perfect for React, will give you out-of-the-box auth and user management.